# Problems while using threading with arguments

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

I have been trying to get this working for a while and I am not very skilled at C++/CLI. I am trying to loop through a 2d array and when it contains certain number create a thread to run but I keep getting errors while compiling.
Here is the thread creation:

```
if (map[x][y] == 8)
{
    Pos^ p = gcnew Pos(x, y, map);
    Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(p, &Pos::moverX));
    t->Start(p);
}
else if (map[x][y] == 9)
{
    Pos^ p = gcnew Pos(x, y, map);
    Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(p, &Pos::moverY));
    t->Start(p);
}
```

Here is the Pos class:

```
public ref class Pos
{
public:
    static int px, py;
    static int ** mapa;
    Pos(int x, int y, int ** map)
    {
        px = x;
        py = y;
        mapa = map;
    }
    int getX(){ return px; }
    int getY(){ return py; }
    int** getMap(){ return mapa; }
    static void moverX(Pos p)
    {
        int dy = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            if (mapa[p.getX()+dy][p.getY()] == 1){ dy *= -1; }
            Console::BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor::Black;
            Console::SetCursorPosition(p.getY() + 30, p.getX() + 5);
            cout << " ";
            Console::SetCursorPosition(p.getY() + 30, p.getX() + 5+dy);
            cout << (char)164;
            Thread::Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    static void moverY(Pos p)
    {
        int dy = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            if (mapa[p.getX()][p.getY() + dy] == 1){ dy *= -1; }
            Console::BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor::Black;
            Console::SetCursorPosition(p.getY() + 30, p.getX() + 5);
            cout << " ";
            Console::SetCursorPosition(p.getY() + 30 + dy, p.getX() + 5);
            cout << (char)164;
            Thread::Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please tell us what your compile errors are. Furthermore, you are using C++/CLI, not C++, so I have changed your question where appropriate.

Comment: Please mark what compiler errors are reported and on which line, otherwise it is nearly impossible to help you.